# Replacing an instrument cluster on an 02 s80 Volvo with a junkyard one?

Tags: volvo, instrument-cluster

Recently went to a junkyard and saw that they had the exact make and model of my moms car. I wanted to do something nice for her. The instrument cluster in her car has been malfunction, sporadically comes on and off. It's a 2002 Volvo s80. Was wondering could I simply pick a instrument cluster off one of the Volvo's in the junkyard and swap it into my moms car? I know for a lot of parts you can do that but not sure if there is something unique about instrument clusters that I should know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The typical cause for these instrument cluster failures is cracked solder joints or cracked traces. Please describe how exactly does the existing cluster fail?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the new(used) cluster would need to be reprogrammed by a dealer or shop with the proper equipment.

You may want to do some basic voltage drop tests on the cluster before deciding to replace. Including checking fuse terminal fit etc...